# Magento 2 Programmatically login user by mail

Tags: magento2, customer, login

I need to connect my user using only email and no password.

I already saw that there is method in customer/session module called `loginById()`

I search but the only thing concerning magento 2 is this :
https://magecomp.com/blog/login-customer-programmatically-without-password-magento-2/

But I don't know what to do with it, i try put it in block and controller but nothing work. I try add the loginById function like this:

```
$customer = $this->_customer->loadByEmail("$mail"); return
$this->_customerSession->loginById($customer->getId());
```

But don't work, my customer is not connected when I change page.

There are many topics on magento 1 like this one: [Programmatically login a user](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34914/programmatically-login-a-user)

But I don't understand very well magento 2 so I can't code magento 2 with magento one solution.

If someone can help me, the final goal is to send mail and user on a page of a custom module with custom block, and if connection is ok he got redirected to the site.

In block i have :

```
protected $_customer;
protected $_customerSession;

public function __construct(
   ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
) {
   ...
    $this->_customer = $customer;
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
}

public function connectUser(){
    $customer = $this->_customer->loadByEmail("jeremie@eurecia.com"); 
    return $this->_customerSession->loginById($customer->getId());
}
```

I call the `connectUser()` function in template.

**EDIT : I don't use SSL (https) cause i dev in local using Wamp (php7).**

Comment: put your whole code

Comment: yes sorry, I add it.