# Login by email without password

Tags: magento-1.9, email, login, programmatically

I would login by email only , without password.

I have Read these two Posts but it not works for me.

[Programmatically login a user](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34914/programmatically-login-a-user)

https://blog.ancud.de/home/-/blogs/magento-how-to-login-a

I use Magento 1.9

This is my code at the momment:

```
function loginByEmail($email, $websiteId)
{
    Mage::init('test', 'website');
    // ensure that we are on the correct website
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
    $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        // the website must be set here again!!!
    $customer->loadByEmail($email);
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

    if ($customer->getId()) {
        $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
        return $session;
    }
}

require_once ( "/var/www/html/app/Mage.php");

Mage::init('test', 'website');
Mage::app("test");


$email = 'test@test.de';
$session = loginByEmail($email,'test');


header('Location: /');
```

I hope you can help me.

thx a lot

so long Maxwill

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code :

```
 $email = 'example@email.com';
 $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
 $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
 $customer->loadByEmail(trim($email));
 Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customer->getId());
```

Comment: Thx for yor answer , but it doesn't work for me.
i will redirect to the login mask.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a print of my customer model:**

```
2019-01-22T12:58:01+00:00 DEBUG (7): Mage_Customer_Model_Customer Object
(
    [_eventPrefix:protected] => customer
    [_eventObject:protected] => customer
    [_errors:protected] => Array()
    [_attributes:protected] => 
    [_addresses:protected] => 
    [_addressesCollection:protected] => 
    [_isDeleteable:protected] => 1
    [_isReadonly:protected] => 
    [_cacheTag:protected] => customer
    [_resourceName:protected] => customer/customer
    [_resource:protected] => 
    [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => customer/customer_collection
    [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1
    [_isObjectNew:protected] => 
    [_data:protected] => Array
    (
        [website_id] => 13
        [entity_id] => 18764
        [entity_type_id] => 1
        [attribute_set_id] => 0
        [email] => test@test.de
        [group_id] => 26
        [increment_id] => 
        [store_id] => 0
        [created_at] => 2018-12-19T16:10:16+01:00
        [updated_at] => 2018-12-19 16:20:04
        [is_active] => 1
        [disable_auto_group_change] => 0
        [default_billing] => 19896
        [default_shipping] => 19896
        [payment_invoice] => 0
        [activate_customer] => 0
        [created_in] => Admin
        [prefix] => 
        [firstname] => fn_test
        [middlename] => mn_test
        [lastname] => ln_test
        [suffix] => 
        [password_hash] => b111111133d4d77d2efecdf74f53b47:N6
        [taxvat] => 
        [rp_token] => 
        [rogler_customer_id] => 
        [cost_center] => 
    )

    [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1
    [_origData:protected] => Array
    (
        [website_id] => 13
        [entity_id] => 18764
        [entity_type_id] => 1
        [attribute_set_id] => 0
        [email] => test@test.de
        [group_id] => 26
        [increment_id] => 
        [store_id] => 0
        [created_at] => 2018-12-19 15:10:16
        [updated_at] => 2018-12-19 16:20:04
        [is_active] => 1
        [disable_auto_group_change] => 0
        [default_billing] => 19896
        [default_shipping] => 19896
        [payment_invoice] => 0
        [activate_customer] => 0
        [created_in] => Admin
        [prefix] => 
        [firstname] => fn_test
        [middlename] => mn_test
        [lastname] => ln_test
        [suffix] => 
        [password_hash] => b1111111111112efecdf74f53b47:N6
        [taxvat] => 
        [rp_token] => 
        [rogler_customer_id] => 
        [cost_center] => 
    )

    [_idFieldName:protected] => entity_id
    [_isDeleted:protected] => 
    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
    (
    )

    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

**And the Session model is:**

```
2019-01-22T12:58:01+00:00 DEBUG (7): Mage_Customer_Model_Session Object
(
    [_customer:protected] => 
    [_isCustomerIdChecked:protected] => 
    [_persistentCustomerGroupId:protected] => 
    [_skipSessionIdFlag:protected] => 
    [_data:protected] => Array
    (
        [_session_validator_data] => Array
            (
                [remote_addr] => 111.111.111.111
                [http_via] => 
                [http_x_forwarded_for] => 
                [http_user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
            )

        [session_hosts] => Array
            (
                [test.de] => 1
            )

        [id] => 18764
    )

    [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1
    [_origData:protected] => 
    [_idFieldName:protected] => 
    [_isDeleted:protected] => 
    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
    (
    )

    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
    (
    )
```

)

**And loginById return 1**

After that i make a "header('Location: /');"

I hope this helps